# Which chapters of the manga do the season 1 and 2 of the Mob Psycho 100 anime cover?

Tags: mob-psycho-100

I'm currently watching Mob Psycho 100, the last episode of season 2 was Mob fighting Keiji Mogami. Which chapters of the manga do the season 1 and 2 of the Mob Psycho 100 anime cover?

Comment: "Last" as in "most recent"? Because season 2 is still airing...

Comment: The first season covers about the first 6-6.5 volumes. There are 16 volumes in total, so depending on how the stuido planned it second season might or might not adapt the remaining 9.5-10 volumes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Season 1 covers Volume 1 through 6. Season 2 will most likely cover Volume 6 through 13.**

Season One ends on Chapter 50 ("No Changes") but also includes an omake chapter ("Romance and Impulse".) at the end of the episode.**

Season Two has covered Chapter 51 through 91.